# Desabilitar checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso de uma ajudar, como faço para desabilitar quando o primeiro checkbox for selecionado.
No link tem um exemplo do que estava montando.

http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/v4s2jep4/1/

Comment: "Preciso de uma ajudar,como faço para desabilitar quando o primeiro checkbox for selecionado". Desabilitar o que ?

Comment: Pode dar mais informações do problema? O que você quer desabilitar ao momento que quem é selecionado?

Comment: Quando clicar no checkbox do visualizar, os checkbox do editar e deletar, tem que ser reabilitado e caso o checkbox do visualizar for desmarcado os checkbox  do editar e deletar tem que ficar desabilitados. @LuisHenrique

Comment: Você prefere que eu faça p/ você ou lhe fale como fazer?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa da forma que vc poder me ajudar, pois terei que estudar o codigo. sou novato em jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao elemento ser clicado, utilize a propriedade `checked` do mesmo para setar a propriedade `disabled` dos outros checkbox, fazendo um find nos mesmos. Vale ressaltar que deve-se usar o contrário do valor boolean, por conta de você querer uma lógica negativa.

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').find('.son').prop('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Atente-se a inserir a classe `son` nos checkbox que deseja serem desabilitados.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo neste link http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/s8pnsm4e/ @LuisHenrique acho que falta alguma coisa.

Comment: Eu havia feito em local aqui utilizando uma div para envolver os checkbox, mudei para td conforme seu html, deve ser algo nisso. @Welguri

Comment: Código atualizado, teste agora @Welguri

Comment: Obrigado @LuisHenrique

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil, marque a mesma como ok. @Welguri